# Error message signing into ADP eTime

Tags: html, authentication, windows-domain, credentials, single-sign-on

This may be a better question for the vendor but I figured I'd see if anyone here is familiar.

The company I work at uses ADP eTime Time and attendance for their employee's timesheets and expense reports.

While working with the user in question, I had just fixed an (im assuming) unrelated issue regarding the incorrect Java version to display the timesheets correctly.

After completing the fix for the above issue, I asked the user to try logging back into ADP. He went through the Timesheet link provided in the company's Sharepoint page which takes you to an authentication page where you are required to enter your Domain credentials. After clicking submit on this page, you would typically be brought right into the timesheet (after selecting Java or HTML mode). In this case, we were presented with the error message below.

Is anyone familiar with this message? I've confirmed that you can log into the users timesheet from another machine with the users credentials. I can't try using another browser to test because Internet Explorer is the only browser that currently works when viewing the timesheet.

[image: Timesheet Sign-on Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what happened but I can now get into the users timesheet.

I will say what the Pingfed recommended and that was to download Fiddler Packet Trace from their website, capture any data received when trying to open the webpage, and forward any information in a .sav file to them to analyze.

While I was running this test, the webpage decided to start working!